# how to rearrange array using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in objective c. I have array please see sample. I need to
    rearrange from 1,2,3 to 2,3,1. Thank you guys.

```
        "M 90.5, 88", <- please pay attention to this
        " C",
        "84.083333373069763, 96.083333253860474", <- 1;
        "87.5, 90.333333253860474", <- 2;
        "84.5, 92.666666507720947", <- 3;
        "M 171, 204", <- please pay attention to this
        " C",
        "161, 199.50000002980232", <- 1;
        "168, 202.33333337306976", <- 2;
        "165, 200.66666674613953", <- 3;
        " C",
        "153.16666674613953, 215.25", <- 1;
        "148.5, 202.66666650772095", <- 2;
        "150, 208.33333301544189", <- 3;
        " C",
        "136.5, 249", <- 1;
        "146.83333349227905, 246.66666662693024", <- 2;
        "141.66666698455811, 247.83333325386047" <- 3;
```

This is my code before and it works in a single Starting point(moveTO) only. what if I draw lots of lines it will create mutliple starting points

like

```
"M 82, 130.5  ",
" 76.333333253860474, 137.16666674613953 ",
" 78.833333253860474, 132.66666674613953 ",
" 75.666666507720947, 134.83333349227905  ",
" 86, 144.5 ",
" 77, 139.5 ",
" 81.5, 142",
"M 146, 137.5  ",
" 147.25, 152.66666674613953 ",
" 146.83333331346512, 142.5 ",
" 147.66666662693024, 147.5  ",
" 141.83333337306976, 166.08333349227905 ",
" 146.83333337306976, 157.83333349227905 ",
" 145.16666674613953, 163.16666698455811  ",
" 128.5, 170 ",
" 138.5, 169 ",
" 133.5, 169.5"

    NSArray *myArray = @[@"M 198.16666666418314, 199.75",@"203.5, 198.5", and so on... ];

    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myArray];

    for(int i=1;i<[newArray count];i=i+3) {
        [newArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:i+2];
        [newArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:i+1];
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to explain what exactly you want to do. `Pay attention to this` and do what??

Comment: M int, int is a starting point of a line or curve. so if you draw 2 lines there will be 2 "M int, int".

Comment: This looks like an SVG command sequence. Is it? You should explain whether you are trying to simply find the methods that will let you interchange array members generally, or if you want to write some chunk of code that will produce a specific transform of input arrays (and if so, exactly what specifies the input and output)

Comment: any help guys. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. thanks guys.

```
   for(int i=1;i<[newArray count];i++) {
      NSString *strMovTo2 = [newArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *elements2 = [strMovTo2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
        newArray2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:elements2];
      for(int j=1;j<[newArray2 count];j=j+3) {
          [newArray2 exchangeObjectAtIndex:j withObjectAtIndex:j+2];
          [newArray2 exchangeObjectAtIndex:j withObjectAtIndex:j+1];
      }


      newArray3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
              for (int y = 2; y<[newArray2 count]; y=y+3){
                  [newArray3 addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", newArray2[y-1], newArray2[y], newArray2[y+1] ]];
              }
      curves = [newArray3 componentsJoinedByString:@" C "];

      MovTOstart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-M %@ C", newArray2[0]];
      [svgFileToPast appendFormat:@"%@ %@", MovTOstart, curves];
  }
```